# Create xaml.cs file

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio, xaml

I writing Windows 10 app and have  two questions.

1) I have XAML file with design, how I can add xaml.cs file , like in screen below 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b2u7.png)

2) I have button, how I can make it to go to another screen by tapping on button

Code for button that I already have:

```
 private void button7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Visual Studio creates a xaml.cs file (code behind) automatically.

2) You can use `Frame.Navigate(typeof(OtherXAMLScreen))`

Comment: I create xaml file, but xaml.cs wasn't created

Comment: @Eugene when you are going to create a new screen, in XAML select white page. If you use XAML view, VS doesn't create the code behind class.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank's.

Comment: about second,
I have Dostavka.xaml.

I need to write code like this Frame.Navigate(typeof(Dostavka))?

Comment: @Eugene yes, that code should be work